# How to Stop printing until calculation of pages finish

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, desktop

I am printing a report in c# , the report has many pages with each page having complex calculations. because there could be many pages and each page can take so long i would like to do the calculation asynchronously.  because this is an engineering problem to a coding problem i removed all the clutter . this is what my code comes down to :

```
  private void StartPrinting(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
  {


     // calculate the total width and height of the printing area of the page

     // -1 just to be conservative
     documentWidth = CalculateDocumentWidth(printDocument, e) - 1;
     // -1 just to be conservative
     documentHeight = CalculateDocumentHeight(printDocument, e) - 1; 

     // calculate the columns and rows of all pages
     // some calculations ....

     // delegate to get results back
     DelegateToReportVoPageStructureDescription theDelegate 
        = ReportPageObjectCalculatedHandler;


     for (int i = 0; i < pageStructureObjects.Count; i++)
     {

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
           // call method to calculate each page here .... 
           // results returned by delegate to 
           // ReportPageObjectCalculatedHandler mehtod
        });

     }

  }
```

the for loop calculate report pages each in separate thread then the result of each calculation process comes to the following method:

```
public void ReportPageObjectCalculatedHandler(VoReportPageObject  voReportPageObject, int pageIndex)
  {

     lock (thisLock) // thread safety
     {
        // assign the calculated page to local variable

        // count how many pages finished calculation

     }

     if ( all pages finished )
     {
        // now i can start printing
     }
  }
```

only when all pages has been processed i can proceed to printing. now you may ask why don't i do all the calculation BEFORE i trigger the printing process? that is because i need the dimensions of the page before i can do any processing .

i can make a loop after the Task.Run(() block to check if all pages has been calculated but this is not good thing to do. i need some way to stop the printing until all pages calculation finished.

how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the tasks returned by the `Task.Run` call into array and use [Task.WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var tasks = new Task[pageStructureObjects.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < pageStructureObjects.Count; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
    {
       // call method to calculate each page here .... 
       // results returned by delegate to 
       // ReportPageObjectCalculatedHandler mehtod
    });
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

But what you are doing seems to be a perfect candidate for [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Parallel.For(0, pageStructureObjects.Count, i =>
{
    // call method to calculate each page here .... 
    // results returned by delegate to 
    // ReportPageObjectCalculatedHandler mehtod
});
```

Comment: "Parallel.For" will wait for all threads to complete before proceeding to the rest of the method ?

Comment: This is what it does - runs everything in parallel, but after the end everything is complete, like after a regular `for`